# Change Images or Bitmap when ever touched on screen

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I want to change the bitmap that contains an image whenever user tap on the screen. i.e. the default image is shadow1, now what i want is that when user touched on screen then this image changed to shadow2, then again if user touched then shadow3, then on next touch the image again comes as shadow1 and it goes on and on and on. so basically there are three images and i want that when ever user touched on screen then image changes with each tap. 
Following is the code that i tried but it is still not working as expected i.e. the image changes from shadow1 to shadow2 but then not changes to shadow3 or shadow1 even if i touched many times.

```
public void Touched(float x, float y)
{
    boom = false;

    try{
        switch (bird.GetState()) {
        case 0:
            distance = 0;
            bird.SetState(1);
            flapped = true;
            Bitmap workingBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameLogic.Resources(), R.drawable.shadow1);
            bitmapBird = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
            if (bitmapBird==workingBitmap)
            {

            }


            riseCounter = 0;
            pipeValues.clear();

            //SoundManager.playSound(2, 1);

            break;
        case 1:
        {
            riseCounter = 0;
            flapped = true;
            t = 3;

            Bitmap workingBitmappp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameLogic.Resources(), R.drawable.shadow2);
            bitmapBird = workingBitmappp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);

            //SoundManager.playSound(2, 1);


        }
        break;
        case 2:
        {
            riseCounter = 0;
            flapped = true;
            t = 0;

        }
        break;
        default:
            Bitmap workingBitma = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameLogic.Resources(), R.drawable.shadow3);
            bitmapBird = workingBitma.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);

            break;
        }
    } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

I think there should be a for loop or while loop in 'case 1' and whenever user tap then image changes. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an `int` value to keep track of the image displayed as;
First Initialize a `int` at class level;

```
 int num = 0;
```

then you can use it as;

```
if(num == 0){
       loadFirstImage();
       num++;
     }
  else if(num == 1)
  {
   loadSecondImage();
   num++;
} 
else if(num == 2){
   loadThirdImage();
   num = 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to change the state of the bird in your second case statement. 
First iteration will set the state to 1, from there, the only case statement you can hit is `case 1:` because you never change it.

So you need something like

```
case 1:
     bird.SetState(2);
     //....
```

Hope that helps